# Is this writing correct

Tags: optimization, notation

Can I define an optimization problem like this to save some space?
$$\min_x f(x)=x^2+1-log(x)\\s.t. ~x>0,$$
or i have to write it as 
$$\min_x f(x)\\s.t. ~x>0,$$
where $f(x)=x^2+1-log(x)$?

**Update**:
In fact, in the real problem, I have a set of constraints like $\{g_i(x)\ge 0\}_{i=1}^k$, and I need to define them in separate lines or with "," in between, but not as the underset of "$\min$".

Comment: The second version is better.

Comment: Indeed I tried the first version to save some space!

Comment: The first looks like it could be saying "the minimum of $f(x)$ is $x^2 +1 - \log(x)$"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My two pence:

$$\min_{x>0}f(x), f(x):=x^2+1-\log x$$

or just

$$\min_{x>0}(x^2+1-\log x)$$

in case you don't need the function elsewhere (or let it be $f(x)$ implicitly).

Comment: Except that it is $-\log(x)$ ! Cheers ;-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: ouch ! Mea culpa ! :-)

Answer (score 1):

No, because this writing is ambiguous, because it is unclear whether you are giving the limit of f (not the second expression) or if you ask the limit of the function (like in the second expression).

I recommend the following:

$\min_{x>0} f(x)=\min_{x>0}(x^2+1-log(x))$

Answer (score 0):

For $f(x)=x^2+1-\ln{x}$ I like the following.
$$\min_{(0,+\infty)}f.$$

Comment: Could you make it shorter, please ?

Comment: If you meant $\min\limits_{x>0}f(x)$ so I don't like this.

Comment: What about $\min_{(0,\infty)}(\text{id}^2+1-\log)$ then ?

Comment: @Yves Daoust I think, it's very ugly.